# jquery-ujs ajax events are not handled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ujs

I'm trying to implement ajaxy signup with rails 3. I'm using jquery-ujs and remote form. I access the signup form with `$.get` request, and it is displayed correctly. This signup form is remote:

```
form_for @user, :remote => true, :html => {"data-type" => "html"} do |f|
```

In my application.js, if the ajax request for getting the form is successful, I'm trying to bind handler for ajax events from unobtrusive javascript:

```
var load_remote_form = function(evt) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    // load form template
    $.get(href, {}, function(data) {
        $('body').append(data);

        $('form[data-remote]').bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(e) {
            console.log("Caught beforeSend!");
        });
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#signup').click(load_remote_form);   
});
```

Chrome's development tools show that the event "`ajax:beforeSend`" is binded, but it is never handled (I have nothing in the javascript console when I send the form, though in rails log I see that the request is processed correctly and the response is send). I can bind other events to the same selector (`form[data-remote]`), like `click`, and they are handled correctly.

Ajax events binded through `.live` are not handled as well. But if the form is rendered as part of the layout (i.e. it is on stand-alone page like http://localhost:3000/signup/), binded "`ajax:beforeSend`" is handled correctly.

My controller (just for a case, it may be badly written, but I'm pretty sure it works):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  layout :layout_for_type

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully registered."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      if request.xhr?
        render :action => 'new', :status => :unprocessable_entry, :layout => false
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def layout_for_type
   request.xhr? ? nil : "application"
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong? May be there is a better approach for implementing such "double-ajaxed" forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. I've completely overlooked another potential source of problems. I had

```
javascript_include_tag :all
```

in my application layout, and that caused including *both* `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js` into my page. It turned out to be the cause of that strange behavior. Removing `jquery.min.js` did the trick. Hope that might be useful for someone someday.